# Corpus studies on the frequency of subject questions in English

Tags: syntax, corpora, questions

Are there any corpus studies which show the relative frequency of different types of interrogative main clauses in English, in particular the relative frequency of subject questions (which do not require subject-auxiliary inversion), other open interrogatives requiring subject auxiliary inversion, and in-situ interrogatives where the *wh*-word occurs in the same position it would occur in a canonical declarative clause?

I am interested in whether the majority of *open* interrogatives that child encounters whilst acquiring the language are more likely to involve subject-auxiliary inversion or not. Or, another way of putting the same question, are the majority of open interrogatives that a child is likely to encounter effectively in situ interrogatives (because subject questions are, in fact, already in situ questions)?

Comment: This is not answerable.

Comment: @Lambie I don't believe  that's the case: there have been many studies of the CHILDES corpus, for example, which compare the frequencies of polar questions and open interrogatives in the speech of native-speaker caregivers to English speaking children.

Comment: caregivers are not children

Comment: @Lambie I'm interested in the language they get as a model whilst acquiring it. But, of course, there are CHILDES corpora of child produced language too. That would be equally estimable.

Comment: What are subject questions??  You should really provide examples. Normal questions with active verbs always require an auxiliary; only ones with the verb be do not. Just the inversion: It's on the table. Where is it?  I like cake. Do you like cake? He is playing with the cat. Is he playing with the cat? How can that be otherwise? Do you mean: open-ended questions as opposed to yes/no questions??

Comment: @Lambie Open questions are ones that begin with *wh* words, unlike closed or yes/no questions that begin with an auxiliary verb. Subject questions do not need an auxiliary verb in English. They are questions like "Who shot J.R?" where the *wh*-word is the subject of the interrogative clause. There is no auxiliary in that sentence.

Comment: Ok, you seem to be covering all question types. In school, children learn questions by types.